# How to remove duplicacy in index path of table view ios,

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

when i increase the quantity of 1st item , the quantity of 7th item increases....  this happens everytime 
 because table view cellforrowatindexPath reloads on scrolling. I am not able to find the solution.How do i solve this.I have searched a lot but could not find any solution Plz help.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MenuSelectCell";
ItemSelectTableViewCell *cell = (ItemSelectTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemSelectTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


    if ([[[self.restaurantModal.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"data" ] count] >0) {
        [cell.selectFlavorBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(selectFlavorMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.addToCartBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addToCart:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.fullQtyPlussBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(updateQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.fullQtyMinusBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(updateQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After you'll scroll, the tableView will not create another cells. It will reuse the cells already created.

> If a cell object is reusable—the typical case—you assign it a reuse
>   identifier (an arbitrary string) in the storyboard. At runtime, the
>   table view stores cell objects in an internal queue. When the table
>   view asks the data source to configure a cell object for display, the
>   data source can access the queued object by sending a
>   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: message to the table view, passing
>   in a reuse identifier. The data source sets the content of the cell
>   and any special properties before returning it. This reuse of cell
>   objects is a performance enhancement because it eliminates the
>   overhead of cell creation.

More details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html). So your code should be like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MenuSelectCell";

    ItemSelectTableViewCell *cell = (ItemSelectTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemSelectTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }


    if ([[[self.restaurantModal.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"data" ] count] >0) {
        [cell.selectFlavorBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(selectFlavorMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.addToCartBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addToCart:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.fullQtyPlussBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(updateQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.fullQtyMinusBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(updateQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason behind this is that your dequed cell still has the parameters from previous index. You can reset before you reuse the cell or you could implement prepareForReuse delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

try 
`ItemSelectTableViewCell *cell = (ItemSelectTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`